# Big Oh Notation Time Complexity

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science

```
i = log(n)

while(i > 0) {
  for(j = 1;j <= exp(2,i);j++) {
    <do some constant time operations>
  }
  i--;
}
```

I think the big oh notation would be O(n*log(n)) because the outer loop is log(n) and the inner loop at most would be 2^log(n) = n and then decrease each iteration. Am I right ?

Comment: That's not actually a question (question mark not withstanding).  You "thought".  Do you not think that now?  Why?  Is there supposed to be a different answer?  What is your intent?

Comment: is this even a question that should be asked on Mathematics? Shouldn't this be on SO?

Comment: @tox123 What is SO ? Stackoverflow ?

Comment: @tox123 This question is best suited at [CS.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) or [TCS.SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I was unaware of CS.SE but this forum does have computer-science and asymptotics as flags.

Comment: @shane Ahh.. In that case, I will provide a response. :)

Answer (score 0):

When considering the inner loop, there will be $$2^{i}, 2^{i-1}, 2^{i-2}, ... , 2^{2}, 2$$ or $$n, \frac{n}{2}, \frac{n}{4}, \frac{n}{8}, .., [\frac{n}{2^{i - lg(n) + 1}} = 2]$$ number of iterations for each decrement of $i$, depending on how you'd like to look at it.

So then, summing these terms yields a closed form formula, which can then be classified with $O$.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{lg(n)}2^{i} = 2^{lg(n) + 1} - 2 \in O(n)$$

used the [geometric series formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_4_%2B_8_%2B_%E2%8B%AF).

---

I believe the error in your approach was only considering the largest value of $j$, which is the first pass through the `while-loop`, instead of including *all* passes through the `while-loop`, a process that involves summing the # of iterations that the `for-loop` performs *for every decrement of $i$.*